# Can I ordain if i have psoriasis?

Tags: theravada, well-being, ordination

Is one able to be ordained if they have psoriasis? It's similar to eczema but not identical? Will this vary depending on where you go to ordain? Thank you.

Comment: Psoriasis is not a terminal illness and it is also not contagious, so I guess it should not be a problem.

Comment: @ruben2020: As far as I know (and have been able to research), eczema isn't terminal or contagious either.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on how severe it is. Two things that are of concern are:

1) Is it visible i.e. on the face or other exposed part of the body such that it puts the faithful followers off?

2) Is it serious such that the itchyness interferes with the cultivation of the practice?

If answers to those two questions are no then there shouldn't be a problem.

I know of a monk who is allergic to wheat and lots who are lacto sensitive.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being argumentative here, but if someone is put off by seeing the suffering of another, I wouldn't call them a "faithful follower" of Buddhism. Also, given that psoriasis worsens (for some sufferers, at least) when the afflicted person is stressed and gets better when when that person relaxes, it seems entirely possible that cultivating practice could lead to a lessening of the condition.

Comment: I am allergic to wheat, and ordained. There are times where psoriasis happens with people. It's a condition of one's immune system. If someone has a cold, do we ordain them? If they have lupus, do we ordain? These are conditions. Suffering is a matter of mind. Discomfort is a matter of physiology. If we observe that someone has not overcome their suffering (even if in pain or discomfort), then we don't ordain. If we observe that these things are not an impediment, then we are free to ordain. I hope that clarifies.